# Can users modify NSUserDefaults key values in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, nsuserdefaults, jailbreak

I have a question about security.

I am making an iOS app with in app purchase following [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases), and I store what products were bought in NSUserDefaults. That's why I wonder :

Can a user with a jailbroken device modify NSUserDefaults key and values for an app?

Thank you very much if you know about it.

Jer

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, they can.  The user defaults are stored relative to your app directory here:

```
./MyAppName.app
./Library/Preferences/com.mycompany.MyAppName.plist
```

The plist file is not encrypted or signed, so it can be modified easily:

```
plutil -convert xml1 com.mycompany.MyAppName.plist
vim com.mycompany.MyAppName.plist
```

You can look into the iOS keychain, as @rckoenes said, or also something [like this open source secure defaults replacement](https://github.com/matthiasplappert/Secure-NSUserDefaults), which offers an interface similar to `NSUserDefaults`.

---

### Update:

Since iOS 8, the data directory (and thus the preferences plist files) are now under:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/<GUID>/Library/Preferences/
```

[Apple Reference Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

Comment: Thank you, the Secure NSUserDefaults you link to looks great for my case, since I don't care the data beeing read, but I want to prevent unauthorized modification :)

Answer (score 8):

Even users without a Jailbroken device can modify plists...

Comment: What's the easiest way to do that?

Comment: The app is called iExplorer. Google it up :-)

Answer (score 4):

Yes a user with a jailbroke device can easily modify the `NSUserDefault` since it's just a plist file in the library directory of your app's sandbox.

You might want to store secure stuff in the keychain, which is a little more secure then the `NSUserDefault`.