# Installing an iPhone Application from a zip of the whole application directory

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

I have a **jailbroken** iPhone, is it possible to take a zip of the entire application directory `(e.g. /private/var/mobile/Applications/{UID})` and then use that **zip** to install the application?

Ultimately, I'm attempting to save the state of this application so I can run tests, and then return it to this state.

Comment: An iOS application does not change while in use. What you probably want to do here is delete the application's preferences and data.

Comment: So, really i want to be able to "drop" an application in the state i save it in from another root level application. so pretty much this application will save off the application (zip it) and then drop it back into place and with a springboard refresh it will be back in its original state.

Comment: @duskwuff, the **executable** does not change while in use, but the contents of the `/var/mobile/Applications/{UID}/` folder does, as that contains the app's docs, caches, user defaults, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

Assuming that the entire **state** of your application is saved in places like the Documents, or Caches folders, or in app preferences (`NSUserDefaults`).

You can make a zip of `/var/mobile/Applications/{UID}`, ssh/scp that .zip file back to your computer (or store it elsewhere on your iPhone), and then unzip it later.

Depending on whether you *move* the app (install it in a different location), or completely delete it at some point, you may need to refresh the list of apps after you restore (unzip the .zip file).  You can do that either by rebooting, respringing (restart SpringBoard), or ssh'ing into the device and issuing the `uicache` command:

```sh
ssh mobile@iphone uicache
```

**Note:** I think you understand this based on your question, but you do need to zip up the whole `/var/mobile/Applications/{UID}/` directory.  Not just the MyAppName.app directory under it.  [That's because, for example, of where the data, user defaults plist, etc. are stored](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12796402/119114).  If you are concerned about the speed of your backup and restore operations, or disk usage, you could probably try to narrow down *which* files you backup (e.g. `./Documents/ and ./Library/`) ... I'll leave that to you.