# Store in-app purchase identifier in sqlite/Core data db, it's safe?

Tags: ios, sqlite, in-app-purchase, nsuserdefaults

I have an in-app purchase that unlock some pro features of my app (a non consumable inapp with restore mechanism). I need to store the in-app identifier in the device to check if a user has already buy the in-app. I want this value availabe quickly when i start the app, i don't wanna wait the return of a webrequest each time the app starts. I have some alternatives to reach this result:

- NsUserDefaults (not safe)
- ios Keychain (safe)
- Alternative git project that "secure" the nsuserDefaults (safe, but seems a bit old project...)

Anyway for some reasons i should prefer to store the identifier in the sqlite db of the app, my question is: A user with a non-jailbreak device can change the content of the db with software like IExplorer ? Something like : Open IExplorer->find db of my app-> change the value for the column "already buyed" -> launch the app and get the pro-features for free...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795120/can-users-modify-nsuserdefaults-key-values-in-an-ios-app

Comment: I know that NsuserDefaults isn't safe, question is about sqlite, it's the same?